# Error while building hello cargo example from docs

Tags: rust, installation

I have installed rust using rustup with the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` option while keeping all other options default. My operating system is Windows 8.
I am following the [rust documentation/book for cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html).

When I run `cargo build`, I get the following error:

```
Compiling hello_cargo v0.1.0 (G:\Rust\hello_cargo)
error: linking with `G:\MinGW\x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "G:\\MinGW\\x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustcjeAAq5\\symbols.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.1njww76hwcxxqiw.rcgu.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.1qzf4kdnnpu2g9nz.rcgu.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.2alld89bz5d1j920.rcgu.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.3od230eh6b5djim5.rcgu.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.3s35zamnay9959j7.rcgu.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.438lj7xxeji9yib.rcgu.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.5fez5aubm3fvq89b.rcgu.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.qszjihs90c7exes.rcgu.o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.2d9vyibnz5v64h8e.rcgu.o" "-L" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,--start-group"
"-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-fefff10efd686913.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-9c45725c63c0d5ed.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libobject-5e1c5cd9ff1eb7cc.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libmemchr-b6bf783b1c783d10.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libaddr2line-2241249e06c7cb40.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_demangle-8def22be308808fe.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_detect-8931bc6a2b527206.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libhashbrown-6e27c0716ec027b4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-c5bbe248c77f2f0b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libadler-9148e9af213d2829.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-47941ef50057df8b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-66b0ea2785827b9a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcfg_if-4b65aaa3f0b095f9.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-04a1f133ddb50e5e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-f67804e146a91ffe.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-a5cbd3ad9e3068dd.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-4bc25ea8e4535542.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-ac0b598a973ccaf7.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-ladvapi32" "-luserenv" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32"
"-lbcrypt" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-L" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-o" "G:\\Rust\\hello_cargo\\target\\debug\\deps\\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "C:\\Users\\Maxim\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: G:\Rust\hello_cargo\target\debug\deps\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.1qzf4kdnnpu2g9nz.rcgu.o: In function `std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace':
          /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52\library\std\src\sys_common/backtrace.rs:118: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          G:\Rust\hello_cargo\target\debug\deps\hello_cargo-1b0993b62f78ade0.3s35zamnay9959j7.rcgu.o: In function `core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once':
          /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52\library\core\src\ops/function.rs:248: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-fefff10efd686913.rlib(std-fefff10efd686913.std.1d6b1f25-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `alloc::collections::btree::mem::replace':
          /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\alloc\src\collections\btree/mem.rs:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-fefff10efd686913.rlib(std-fefff10efd686913.std.1d6b1f25-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `<std::io::Write::write_fmt::Adapter<T> as core::fmt::Write>::write_str':
          /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\std\src\io/mod.rs:1664: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-fefff10efd686913.rlib(std-fefff10efd686913.std.1d6b1f25-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `<std::io::Write::write_fmt::Adapter<T> as core::fmt::Write>::write_str':
          /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\std\src\io/mod.rs:1664: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libstd-fefff10efd686913.rlib(std-fefff10efd686913.std.1d6b1f25-cgu.0.rcgu.o):/rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\std\src\io/mod.rs:1664: more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libpanic_unwind-9c45725c63c0d5ed.rlib(panic_unwind-9c45725c63c0d5ed.panic_unwind.cb21c7dc-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `panic_unwind::real_imp::panic':
          /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\panic_unwind\src/gcc.rs:62: undefined reference to `_Unwind_RaiseException'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libpanic_unwind-9c45725c63c0d5ed.rlib(panic_unwind-9c45725c63c0d5ed.panic_unwind.cb21c7dc-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `alloc::boxed::Box<T>::new':
          /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\alloc\src/boxed.rs:(.text+0x418): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libpanic_unwind-9c45725c63c0d5ed.rlib(panic_unwind-9c45725c63c0d5ed.panic_unwind.cb21c7dc-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `rust_eh_personality':
          /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\panic_unwind\src/gcc.rs:276: undefined reference to `_GCC_specific_handler'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libobject-5e1c5cd9ff1eb7cc.rlib(object-5e1c5cd9ff1eb7cc.object.c08054e5-cgu.0.rcgu.o):object.c08054e5-cg:(.text+0x1f95): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libobject-5e1c5cd9ff1eb7cc.rlib(object-5e1c5cd9ff1eb7cc.object.c08054e5-cgu.0.rcgu.o):object.c08054e5-cg:(.text+0x2b12): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libgimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.rlib(gimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.gimli.823974b0-cgu.0.rcgu.o):gimli.823974b0-cgu:(.text+0xc2e): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libgimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.rlib(gimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.gimli.823974b0-cgu.0.rcgu.o):gimli.823974b0-cgu:(.text+0x2be7): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libgimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.rlib(gimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.gimli.823974b0-cgu.0.rcgu.o):gimli.823974b0-cgu:(.text+0x2c76): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
          C:\Users\Maxim\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\libgimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.rlib(gimli-03f5272f7c5d2bd2.gimli.823974b0-cgu.0.rcgu.o):gimli.823974b0-cgu:(.text+0x2e1f): more undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
          collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

  = help: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)
```

I deleted and reinstalled rust but the results were the same.
I didn't find anything useful on google. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install rust? I'm thinking your rust is corrupted or misconfigured. 
You can try to type 'rustup update' in your terminal see if it works after that.

Comment: @AustinHamner I tried 'rustup update' but the results were the same. I installed rust using rustup. I chose the second option to change the toolchain to 'x86_64-pc-windows-gnu'. Operating System: Windows 8.